# pass object parameter to an adapter that takes javascribt object

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm working on a native iOS Swift app that is integrated with a Worklight server, the issue I'm having is that on of the adapters take an object "params" as a parameter, and this object is a javascript object, but when I'm trying to call this adapter from my native app, the server keeps giving response that the parameter is missing, here is a code snippet:

```
let procedure = WLProcedureInvocationData(adapterName: adapterNameTextField.text, procedureName: procedureNameTextField.text)

procedure.parameters = ["en","firas@cloudappers.com","123123123"]

WLClient.sharedInstance().invokeProcedure(procedure, withDelegate: ProcedureDelegate(master: self))
```

and here is the adapter's procedure header:

```
function findCardKey(language,userId,params) {

    var request = '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xs="..." xmlns:xs1="....">'
        +getHeader(language,userId)
        +'<soapenv:Body>'
            +'<xs1:findCardKeyRequest>'
                +jsonToXml(params,'', null) 
            +'</xs1:findCardKeyRequest>'
        +'</soapenv:Body>'
    +'</soapenv:Envelope>';

    var result = invokeWebService(request,"findCardKey");

    return result;

}
```

This params is a javascript object that contains an attribute named "tagId".

here is where it is called in a hybrid app in `CardEnquiryServiceModel`:

```
findCardKey: function(parameters, callback, userId) 
{
    var invocationData = 
    {
        adapter: 'nolCardEnquiryv2Service',
        procedure: 'findCardKey',
        parameters: [GeneralUtil.getServerLanguage(), userId, parameters]
    };

    InvokeUtil.invokeProcedure(invocationData, null, callback);

}
```

and here is where it's used:

```
var parameters = {};
parameters.tagId = $("#tagIdInput").val();
CardEnquiryServiceModel.findCardKey(parameters, _this.getCardEnquiryServiceFindCardKeyResult, user_id);
```

what is the form or the type or the way that I should use to pass this object to the adapter in iOS Swift?

Comment: You need to add the actual implementation of findCardKey, as this is where you are actually using the params object. As it is, params is just a string and not an object as it is evident in your code snippet that you're passing "123123123" and not an object.

Comment: Thanks for the update. So if it's in a hybrid app, what does a native swift app got to do with it? Are you in fact saying that you're trying to implement your hybrid app as a native app?

Comment: I'm working on the same adapters that are used previously in a hybrid app to develop a new native app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the data in a dictionary:

`let myDictionary = ["YYZ": "Toronto Pearson", "DUB": "Dublin"]`

Then add it to the invocationData:

`invocationData.parameters = ["en","firas@cloudappers.com",myDictionary]`

Everything together, for example:

```
let myDictionary = ["YYZ": "Toronto Pearson", "DUB": "Dublin"]
let invocationData = WLProcedureInvocationData(adapterName: "RSSReader", procedureName: "getStories")
invocationData.parameters = ["en","firas@cloudappers.com",myDictionary]
WLClient.sharedInstance().invokeProcedure(invocationData, withDelegate: invokeListener)
```

In the adapter code, make sure to JSON.stringify it. For example:

```
function getStories(language, email, params) {
    WL.Logger.info("language: " + language + ", " + "email: " + email + ", " + "params: " + JSON.stringify(params));
    ...
    ... 
    ...
}
```